# Switch source of embedded Vimeo video clicking on a thumbnail image

Tags: jquery, iframe, video, vimeo

I have an `iframe` for embedding a `Vimeo video` inside a div of a carousel menu. Below the menu there are 2 thumbnail images of the videos. The thumbnails are composed by an image and an overlay play button image (I used `z-index` for putting it on top). I gave an `id` to the overlay play button image and I targeted that in the `click` event for changing the video source in the iframe. (Be sure to click on `Galleria video` in the carousel menu in order to be able to see what is shown in the screenshot.)

[image: video]

I used JQuery for that and I tried 2 ways:

**First method**:
I tried to replace the whole **html** for the `iframe` inside the `div`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $("#playbutton, #playbutton2").on("click", function(e) {
        var videoplayer = "";
        switch ($(this).prop("id")) {
            case "playbutton":
                videoplayer = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/87204743" width="577" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                break;
            case "playbutton2":
                videoplayer = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/87198074" width="577" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                break;
                }
            $("#video-vimeo").html(videoplayer);
            return false;
    })
})
</script>
```

`#playbutton` and `playbutton2` are the IDs of the overlay play buttons of the thumbnails. `videoplayer` is a variable I used for storing the html code. `#video-vimeo` is the `ID` of the `div` that contains the embedded video.

See [here](http://tinyurl.com/lm92cmk) for the live page (The JQuery code is at the end of the html page).

**Second method**: I tried to replace only the value of the **src** attribute of the `iframe` inside the `div`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $("#playbutton, #playbutton2").on("click", function(e) {
        var videoplayer = "";
        switch ($(this).prop("id")) {
            case "playbutton":
                alert("video1");
                videoplayer = "//player.vimeo.com/video/87204743";
                break;
            case "playbutton2":
                alert("video2");
                videoplayer = "//player.vimeo.com/video/87198074";
                break;
                }
            $("#video-iframe").attr("src", videoplayer);
            return false;
    })
})
</script>
```

`#video-iframe` here is the **ID** of the `iframe` I want to target.

See [here](http://tinyurl.com/oqeojbm) for the live page (The JQuery code is at the end of the html page).

---

I think my ideas should be good but it doesn't work and at the moment I can't see the mistake. I hope you can help me to solve the problem and if you have better ideas feel free to tell me.

Comment: Your second method works, but code is not on page at all. I copied it and run in console: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0dtp9fcg1gfklh7/Screenshot%202014-02-25%2002.07.41.png UPD: sorry, now I see it on page. So, code itself works. It means that when you run it, buttons `#playbutton, #playbutton2` are not existed yet. Is it created programmatically?

Comment: UPD2: yes. you do. Page code is really a mess, easiest solution will be delegate event to body: `$("body").on("click", "#playbutton,#playbutton2", function() { your_code_here; })`

Comment: It is a website with a single page and everything that isn't shown at the beginning (included the video and the thumbnails) are generated programmatically. So do you have an idea how I could solve the problem?

Comment: yes, I'm aware the code is a mess (I have to refactor it). Now I try what you suggested and I let you know if it works.

Comment: I used your code and inserted my function, anyway it seems there's a syntax error. Could you check what I did wrong? http://tinyurl.com/olycbdq

Comment: You closed your function with closing curly bracket twice. Bracket on line 492 is wrong one.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. I used an alert() function just for seeing if the click event is fired. Now it is, anyway I still didn't achieve what I want. When I click on the thumbnail, the video should change, instead nothing happens and the original video is always displayed. http://tinyurl.com/olycbdq

Comment: If link is the same, I don't see you use delegate click to body: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwqx6s9ja5125c5/2014-02-25_02-54-21.png

Comment: Check this link: http://tinyurl.com/olycbdq

Comment: You access your video frame with `$("#video-iframe")`, but element with such id does not exists. Actually, iframe with player does not have _any_ id assigned: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsdidrsdvibkmt3/2014-02-25_03-00-41.png You really should to investigate how to debug javascript in browser.

Comment: I had multiple versions of the page and I edited another page in order not to touch the previously linked page and keep it as a reference. Unfortunately that page didn't have the id assigned to the iframe. I fixed it adding the id and it finally works. Thanks. You solved my problem.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't replace the whole iframe with another iframe? your current method is incredibly dependent on Vimeo's iframe embed system, and if that ever changes you will have to update all your code. I think a more reliable solution would be to use oEmbed to generate the new iframe, and swap them out entirely.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion..i used embedly before that uses oEmbed and then decided to get back to the simple iframe vimeo player..anyway I'll consider it again.